# Type annotation for Callables with *args

Tags: python-3.6, python-3.5, python-typing

I know how to type-annotate functions which take arguments.

```py
def function(text: str, *args: int) -> None:
    print(text)
    for arg in args:
        print(arg)
```

My problem, however, is that I don't know what this looks like when another function takes it as an input:

```py
def introduce(foo: Callable[[str, XXX], None], text: str, *args: int) -> None:
    print("Enter...")
    foo(text, *args)
    print("Exit...")

introduce(function, "Hello, World!", (1, 2, 3))
```

Naturally, the `XXX` represents whatever it is that `*args` is supposed to be. However, I can't figure that out, and I've been unable to intuit what belongs there. I don't think it would be `int`, as that would suggest exactly one proceeding value. Experimentation has failed me here.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I'm facing exactly the same problem

Comment: Sadly not. I had one person privately suggest that it may involve generics, but he wasn't sure. I started to wonder at one point if there had been an oversight in PEP 526, although it seems like a problem that would happen all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the more recent introduction of TypeVarTuple, it seems this question is now soluble. I've set this up so that `introduce` only has to match the `args` types, making it more generic:

```py
from typing import Callable, TypeVarTuple

Ts = TypeVarTuple("Ts")

def function(text: str, *args: int) -> None:
    print(text)
    for arg in args:
        print(arg)

def introduce(foo: Callable[[str, *Ts], None], text: str, *args: *Ts) -> None:
    print("Enter...")
    foo(text, *args)
    print("Exit...")

introduce(function, "Hello, World!", *(1, 2, 3))
```